# Scaling Flex Graphic Object via UI

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, transform, scaling, primitive

I have basic shapes created using flex  primitives classes like ellipse rectangle etc. Each of these are added into a graphic object.

Now i am in search of a mechanism to select it and scale it (as in Photoshop Transform -dragable corners and edges, image gets scaled on dragging)

Any solutions available??

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of spark graphic primitives extend InteractiveObject class so you won`t be able to manipulate them directly in any way. Here is what I think you should do (more Actionscript-like thinking): create a sprite, draw shape you need using AS3 drawing API, then addChild that shape to your sprite along with additional small sprites that mark areas where you should be able to interact with your graphic. For example if you want to scale your main sprite when a corner is grabbed, just add a small sprite to to the corner area and listen for mouseDown event on that little sprite (along with mouseMove event to determine how much your main sprite should resize).

There may be some easier way with some Flex goodies, but as I said - this is what I`d do with pure AS.

Comment: Well, I just think that there may already be some custom wrapper or skin written by someone to ease the task of resizing and dragging comps. [Here`s something](http://mobile.dzone.com/news/flex-4-spark-resizable) that may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: http://code.google.com/p/transform-tool/